# Get the order ID on the final checkout page when a customer purchased a product in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, orders

I'm developing a plugin that needs to get the order ID on the final checkout page when a customer purchased a product. How do I do that?
I tried

```
global $order
var_dump($order);
```

And all I see is "DESC". I need to access the current order of the customer who is looking at the page.

I need to get the order id in the frontend and add that ID to a script, also on the front end, so that when a client orders a product and pays, the page will load, show them the "Thank you, here is your order number: xxx". At that moment I need my script to, for example, execute a `console.log("The oder ID is:", order_id);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the order ID on the final checkout page when a customer purchased a product you can use the `woocommerce_thankyou` hook, where the callback function already contains the order ID.

```
// define the woocommerce_thankyou callback 
function action_woocommerce_thankyou( $order_id ) {
    echo "Thank you, here is your order ID: " . $order_id;

    // Get an instance of the WC_Order object
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    // Customer billing country
    $billing_country = $order->get_billing_country();

    // etc..
}; 
         
// add the action 
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'action_woocommerce_thankyou', 10, 1 );
```